# testing filters in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm new to laravel. I am trying to test that authentication works for my website and I want to test the authentication process in a test case. I create a in-memory sqlite database, I create a new User and use `->save()` method of eloquent to store it in the database. I have setup an authentication filter which checks for the username in the database and depending on that it either allows the user to login or returns "invalid credentials"

// my UserTest.php file :

```
class UserTest extends TestCase {

public function testUsernameIsNotRequired()
{
    // Create a new User
    $user = new User;
    $user->username = "phil@ipbrown.com";
    $user->password = "123456";
    //$user->password_confirmation = "password";

    // User should save
    $this->assertTrue($user->save());

    // Save the errors
    $password = $user->getAuthPassword();

    // There should be 0 error
    $this->assertEquals("123456",$password);
    $this->seed();

    $this->be($user);

    $this->assertTrue(Redirect::route('authFilter'));
}
}
```

just to let you know that the in-memory db is lost once the test is complete as all the connections to it are lost so I want to check that the user that I saved to my db is properly inserted and second I want to check if I can login to my website using the information of this new user.

// my filters.php file :

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});
```

I was trying to attach a filter to a route so that I can redirect to the route during my test and which calls the auth.basic filter so I can test my filter, I know Im doing a lot of things wrong so please feel free to correct any mistakes that you come accross

my routes.php file :>

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/authtest', array('as'=>'/authtest','before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
     return View::make('hello');
}));

Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'auth.basic'), function()
{
    Route::resource('url', 'UrlController');
});

Route::get('authFilter', array('as'=>'authFilter','before' => 'auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
}));
```

I also have a uri controller which has all the pages for my website

[this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/laravel-4-a-start-at-a-restful-api/) is what I followed to create my uri controller for the moment

I need a test case that creates a user stores it into the in-memory database and then authenticates using that users information. If any one knows laravel testing for filters please let me know I looked up the documentation for testing filters but I guess it is not well documented.

thank you

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 13.00Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) UserTest::testUsernameIsNotRequired
Failed asserting that Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse Object (
    'request' => Illuminate\Http\Request Object ( . . . . . . . .

FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 3, Failures: 1.

Answer (score 24):

Filters are disabled in tests on Laravel 4.

You can use `Route::enableFilters()` in your test to force the filters on.

You can read up on the various discussions about why/why not to test filters;

- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/344
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/766
- http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=7404
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/682

Comment: Those links don't seem to have an actual "discussion" about why/why-not, only assertions that you "should" test each component in isolation.

Though this comment doesn't have room to go into detail, a couple of arguments are:

1) You "should" test components in isolation because unit tests should not rely on external dependencies (which multiplies test requirements)

2) You "should not" test controllers without filters because this results in tight coupling - rather than checking that a controller action behaves correctly, you rely on it having a particular implementation of that behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You can keep most of this in the unit test.

```
public function testMyFilter() {
 // Set up route with filter.                                                
 Route::get('testFilter', ['before' => 'myfilter',  function()   
 {                                                                  
         return 'Hello World';                                      
 }]);
 // Enable filters.
 Route::enableFilters(); 

 // Be a user.
 $this->be($this->user);

 // Make a request that will use the filter.                                   
 $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'testFilter'); 

 // Check the response.
 $this->assertResponseOk(); 
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, but I get: Fatal error: Call to a member function driver() on a non-object in /project/directory/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/ApplicationTrait.php on line 165
 when running the test.

Comment: Oops! looks like it's because I didn't include "parent::setUp();" in my setUp function.